# How to copy keyboard layout from one computer to another in Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, keyboard-layout, qwerty

I need “Russian (US, phonetic)” keyboard layout on Debian 12 bookworm. Where it's not currently available. But I have it on a different computer that's running Debian Trixie/sid.

Can I somehow copy it to Debian 12. Without upgrading the entire system to Debian Trixie/sid?